# how to avoid the duplicated job in github action like build image?

Tags: github, github-actions

there are some workflows in a repository and triggered by push behavior.(sometime a push will trigger 2 workflows, sometimes will trigger 5 workflows)
but there are some common works like 'build docker image' for integration test.
I'm not sure how to avoid the duplicated work, I tried reuable workflow, but that will build the image 2 or more times。

is there anyway like the `needs` keywork to make all triggered action depends on the same job result ？

Answer (score 2):

Check if your use case is similar to "[Avoid re-running wokflow for the same commit](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/27031)", with [Samuel Ryan](https://github.com/shrink)'s workaround:

> Yes, you can use the [Check Runs API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/checks) to identify [Workflow runs for a ref](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/checks#list-check-runs-for-a-git-reference).
> As luck would have it, someone has already built a comprehensive Action for this use-case: [`fkirc/skip-duplicate-actions`](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/skip-duplicate-actions).
>
> - Add a new “pre” job to your Workflow, this job uses `fkirc/skip-duplicate-actions` to determine if your main job should be skipped
> - Add a condition to your main job using the should_skip output of the “pre” job.
>
> For example, adapted from the [`fkirc/skip-duplicate-actions` README](https://github.com/fkirc/skip-duplicate-actions#skip-duplicate-actions):
>
> ```yaml
> jobs:
>  pre_job:
>    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
>    outputs:
>      should_skip: ${{ steps.skip_check.outputs.should_skip }}
>    steps:
>      - id: skip_check
>        uses: fkirc/skip-duplicate-actions@v3.4.0
>        with:
>          skip_after_successful_duplicate: 'true'
>  main_job:
>    needs: pre_job
>    if: ${{ needs.pre_job.outputs.should_skip != 'true' }}
>    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
>    steps:
>      - run: echo "Running slow tests..." && sleep 30
> ```

Comment: thank you for your response. this action is really powerful, let me have a try.
thank you.